# I get this error when trying to verify the email of candidates, Array to String conversion

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel system that when someone registers, they get a link on their emails where they have to click on it to verify their email. Once they click the link, their information is stored in the users table and the candidates table.
However, values are only inserted in the users table and not the candidates table, and I get the error "Array to string conversion".
Also, the link works well in local host but not after hosting the system.
[RegisiterController.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suXfA.png)
[Str.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKRua.png)`

```
    public function registerCandidate(Request $request){
    if(setting('general_enable_candidate_registration')!=1){
        return abort(401);
    }

    $rules = [
        'first_name'=>'required',
        'last_name'=>'required',
        'national_id'=>'required',
        'gender'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required|email|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'date_of_birth_year'=>'required',
        'date_of_birth_month'=>'required',
        'date_of_birth_day'=>'required',
        'categories'=>'required',
        'picture' => 'nullable|max:'.config('app.upload_size').'|mimes:jpeg,png,gif',
        'cv_path' => 'nullable|max:'.config('app.upload_size').'|mimes:'.config('app.upload_files'),
    ];

    if(setting('general_candidate_captcha')==1){
        $rules['captcha'] = 'required|captcha';
    }

    foreach(CandidateFieldGroup::where('registration',1)->orderBy('sort_order')->get() as $group){

        foreach($group->candidateFields as $field){

            if($field->type=='file'){
                $required = '';
                if($field->required==1){
                    $required = 'required|';
                }

                $rules['field_'.$field->id] = 'nullable|'.$required.'max:'.config('app.upload_size').'|mimes:'.config('app.upload_files');
            }
            elseif($field->required==1){
                $rules['field_'.$field->id] = 'required';
            }
        }

    }




    $this->validate($request,$rules);
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $password= $request->password;

    $requestData['name']= $request->first_name.' '.$request->last_name;
    $requestData['display_name'] = $request->first_name;
    $requestData['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    $requestData['role_id'] = 3;

    $fields = CandidateField::get();




    //check if email verification is required
    if(setting('general_candidate_verification')==1){

        do{
            $hash = Str::random(30);
        }while(PendingUser::where('hash',$hash)->first());


        $formData = $_POST;

        $formData['name'] = $request->first_name.' '.$request->last_name;
        $formData['display_name'] = $request->first_name;
        $formData['role_id'] = 3;

        if($request->hasFile('picture')) {

            $path =  $request->file('picture')->store(PENDING_USER_FILES,'public_uploads');

            $file = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$path;
            $img = Image::make($file);

            $img->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                $constraint->upsize();
            });
            $img->save($file);

            $formData['picture'] = $file;
        }
        else{

            $formData['picture'] =null;
        }

        if($request->hasFile('cv_path')) {

            //$path =  $request->file('cv_path')->store(CANDIDATES,'public_uploads');

            $name = $_FILES['cv_path']['name'];

            $extension = $request->cv_path->extension();
            //  dd($extension);

            $name = str_ireplace('.'.$extension,'',$name);

            $name = uniqid().'_'.time().'_'.safeUrl($name).'.'.$extension;

            $path =  $request->file('cv_path')->storeAs(PENDING_USER_FILES,$name,'public_uploads');



            $file = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$path;

            $formData['cv_path'] = $file;
        }
        else{

            $formData['cv_path'] =null;
        }


        $pendingUser = PendingUser::create([
            'role_id'=>3,
            'data'=> serialize($formData),
            'hash'=> $hash
        ]);

        //scan for files
        foreach($fields as $field){
            if(isset($requestData['field_'.$field->id]) && $field->type=='file' && $request->hasFile('field_'.$field->id))
            {
                //generate name for file

                $name = $_FILES['field_'.$field->id]['name'];

                //dd($name);


                $extension = $request->{'field_'.$field->id}->extension();
                //  dd($extension);

                $name = str_ireplace('.'.$extension,'',$name);

                $name = $pendingUser->id.'_'.time().'_'.safeUrl($name).'.'.$extension;

                $path =  $request->file('field_'.$field->id)->storeAs(PENDING_USER_FILES,$name,'public_uploads');



                $file = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$path;
                $pendingUser->pendingUserFiles()->create([
                    'file_name'=>$_FILES['field_'.$field->id]['name'],
                    'file_path'=>$file,
                    'field_id'=>$field->id
                ]);

            }


        }

        //send email to user
        $link = route('confirm.candidate',['hash'=>$hash]);
        $this->sendEmail($request->email,__('site.confirm-your-email'),__('site.confirm-email-mail',['link'=>$link]));
        return redirect()->route('register.confirm');
    }




    //First create user
    $user= User::create($requestData);

    //Calculate date of birth
    $dateOfBirth = $request->date_of_birth_year.'-'.$request->date_of_birth_month.'-'.$request->date_of_birth_day;
    $requestData['date_of_birth'] = $dateOfBirth;

    //checkfor picture
    if($request->hasFile('picture')) {

        $path =  $request->file('picture')->store(CANDIDATES,'public_uploads');

        $file = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$path;
        $img = Image::make($file);

        $img->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });
        $img->save($file);

        $requestData['picture'] = $file;
    }
    else{

        $requestData['picture'] =null;
    }

    if($request->hasFile('cv_path')) {

        //$path =  $request->file('cv_path')->store(CANDIDATES,'public_uploads');

        $name = $_FILES['cv_path']['name'];

        $extension = $request->cv_path->extension();
        //  dd($extension);

        $name = str_ireplace('.'.$extension,'',$name);

        $name = $user->id.'_'.time().'_'.safeUrl($name).'.'.$extension;

        $path =  $request->file('cv_path')->storeAs(CANDIDATE_FILES,$name,'public_uploads');



        $file = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$path;

        $requestData['cv_path'] = $file;
    }
    else{

        $requestData['cv_path'] =null;
    }


    $user->candidate()->create($requestData);

    //save categories
    
    $user->candidate->categories()->attach($request->categories);

    //now save custom fields


    $customValues = [];
    //attach custom values
    foreach($fields as $field){
        if(isset($requestData['field_'.$field->id]))
        {

            if($field->type=='file'){
                if($request->hasFile('field_'.$field->id)){
                    //generate name for file

                    $name = $_FILES['field_'.$field->id]['name'];

                    $extension = $request->{'field_'.$field->id}->extension();

                    $name = str_ireplace('.'.$extension,'',$name);

                    $name = $user->id.'_'.time().'_'.safeUrl($name).'.'.$extension;

                    $path =  $request->file('field_'.$field->id)->storeAs(CANDIDATE_FILES,$name,'public_uploads');

                    $file = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$path;
                    $customValues[$field->id] = ['value'=>$file];
                }
            }
            else{
                $customValues[$field->id] = ['value'=>$requestData['field_'.$field->id]];
            }
        }


    }

    $user->candidateFields()->sync($customValues);

    $message = __('mails.new-account',[
        'siteName'=>setting('general_site_name'),
        'email'=>$requestData['email'],
        'password'=>$password,
        'link'=> url('/login')
    ]);
    $subject = __('mails.new-account-subj',[
        'siteName'=>setting('general_site_name')
    ]);
    $this->sendEmail($requestData['email'],$subject,$message);

    //now login user
    Auth::login($user, true);

    //redirect to relevant page
    if(session()->exists('candidate_destination')){
        $url = session()->get('candidate_destination');
        session()->remove('candidate_destination');
        return redirect($url);
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

}

   
    
   public function confirmCandidate($hash){
    //get pending user
    $pendingUser = PendingUser::where('hash',$hash)->first();
    if(!$pendingUser){
        abort(404);
    }

    $requestData = unserialize($pendingUser->data);
    $password = $requestData['password'];
    $requestData['password'] = Hash::make($password);

    //check for profile picture and move to new directory
    if(!empty($requestData['picture']) && file_exists($requestData['picture'])){

        $file = basename($requestData['picture']);

        $newPath = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.CANDIDATES.'/'.$file;
        rename($requestData['picture'],$newPath);
        $requestData['picture'] = $newPath;

    }

    if(!empty($requestData['cv_path']) && file_exists($requestData['cv_path'])){

        $file = basename($requestData['cv_path']);

        $newPath = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.CANDIDATE_FILES.'/'.$file;
        rename($requestData['cv_path'],$newPath);
        $requestData['cv_path'] = $newPath;

    }


    //First create user
    $user= User::create($requestData);

    //Calculate date of birth
    $dateOfBirth = $requestData['date_of_birth_year'].'-'.$requestData['date_of_birth_month'].'-'.$requestData['date_of_birth_day'];
    $requestData['date_of_birth'] = $dateOfBirth;

    $user->candidate()->create($requestData);

    //save categories
    if(isset($requestData['categories'])){
        $user->candidate->categories()->attach($requestData['categories']);
    }


    $fields = CandidateField::get();

    $customValues = [];
    //attach custom values
    foreach($fields as $field){

        if($field->type=='file'){
            $pendingFile = $pendingUser->pendingUserFiles()->where('field_id',$field->id)->first();

            if($pendingFile){

                //generate name for file
                $name = $pendingFile->file_name;

                $info = new \SplFileInfo($name);

                $extension = $info->getExtension();

                $name = str_ireplace('.'.$extension,'',$name);

                $name = $user->id.'_'.time().'_'.safeUrl($name).'.'.$extension;

                $file = UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.CANDIDATE_FILES.'/'.$name;

                rename($pendingFile->file_path,$file);

                $customValues[$field->id] = ['value'=>$file];
            }
        }
        elseif(isset($requestData['field_'.$field->id])){
            $customValues[$field->id] = ['value'=>$requestData['field_'.$field->id]];
        }


    }

    $user->candidateFields()->sync($customValues);
    $pendingUser->delete();

    $message = __('mails.new-account',[
        'siteName'=>setting('general_site_name'),
        'email'=>$requestData['email'],
        'password'=>$password,
        'link'=> url('/login')
    ]);
    $subject = __('mails.new-account-subj',[
        'siteName'=>setting('general_site_name')
    ]);
    $this->sendEmail($requestData['email'],$subject,$message);

    //now login user
    Auth::login($user, true);

    //redirect to relevant page
    if(session()->exists('candidate_destination')){
        $url = session()->get('candidate_destination');
        session()->remove('candidate_destination');
        return redirect($url);
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

`

Comment: The `request` data you are receiving does not comply with the data format required to store in the Database. Verify the data in the request. If still can't solve, add DB table structure and request data to your question and the community will help you figure it out.

Comment: Thank you jerry555555, the issue was with the data format of the values being requested.